# I can't install the nmap module on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVFf4.png)
hello I have a problem with my python code that I am creating I wanted to import the nmap module on my code but I have a problem with line 5 of the module

someone would have a little idea please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLqh5.png)

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: As far as your specific problem is concerned, you need to install the `nmap` binary on your system and put it in your Windows `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The nmap Python module only works if you actually have nmap installed. It doesn't come by default on Windows. You can get it [here](https://nmap.en.lo4d.com/windows).